# Is it possible to delay a <a target="_blank"> click?

Tags: javascript

Say I want to delay some seconds after clicking on a `<a>` link.

I have read some questions and found one here:

```
function delay (URL) {
    setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, 500 );
}
```

However, this would make the page opened in the current window. Not a new one.

How can I have the effect to make it work as `target=_blank` while NOT using `window.open` popups? Is that even possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? This might be a XY problem.

Comment: Don't think there is any way other than window.open . Hope others come up with something.

Comment: @IngoBürk sorry what is an XY problem?

Answer (score 2):

Read the answer: [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

But I imagine you can emulate a click on `<a>`

```
<a id="link" style="display: none;" href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
<button id="trigger">Trigger</button>

<script>
    const trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
    trigger.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('link').click();
      }, 500);
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open) function while specifying the second argument as `_blank`:

`window.open(URL, "_blank")` have the same effect as `target=_blank`.

Comment: He explicitly asked doing it without `window.open`.

Comment: I think he might not be aware of the second parameter. I am posting this just for assurance as it might be helpful.